# Proof verification: $\sin(Arccos(x))$ is always positive, regardless of $x$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

$\sin(Arccos(x)) \implies \sin(Arcsin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x))$ and since $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ then we can have as the maximal and minimal values in the $Arcsin,$ $\frac{\pi}{2}-(-1)\approx2.57$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}-1\approx0.57.$ But $\sin$ only accepts values up to $1$ so I capped the range of values to $\approx [0.57, 1].$ The $\sin$ values for this range are between $0$ and $1.$

I'm a total beginner so please don't hold back in your critiquing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the most commonly accepted definition of arc cosine, for every $x\in[-1,1]$
$$
0\le\arccos x\le \pi
$$
so
$$
\sin\arccos x\ge0
$$

Note. Never substitute $\pi$ with $3.14$ unless at the last moment if you need a numeric answer. And the sine accepts *any* value (it returns only values in $[-1,1]$).

Comment: Why is arc cos not 0 < arccos x < 2π?

Comment: @Orion Because the cosine is not injective over $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^{-1} (\cos x) = \frac \pi2 - x$ but that isn't what you have.

$\sin (\cos^{-1}x) = \sqrt {1-x^2}$

And, the best way to learn this is to draw triangles in your unit circle and think about what each of these functions represents.